# Hi! I have bmw 318d e91 one week ago start to leak oil

Tags: oil, leak

[image][image]

Oil leak start from under the filter it’s very hard to fix so I am wishing to have your advice what to do

Comment: Check the filter and seal are fitted properly. Location of seal and tightness.

Answer (score 1):

Generally: Oil leaks are sometimes hard to find: wind, vibration an temperature can distribute oil pretty good. If you are not sure where it comes from, clean and let the motor run until it appears again. Sometimes a piece of cardboard under the motor to drip on, over night, can help too.

In your case: Most likely place it the Oil-filter. Look if the O-ring is seated correctly. Sometimes the old O-ring is stuck to the motor and when you screw on the new filter you have it doubled so the seal won´t hold. Make sure that the sealing surface is clean, without grooves or scratches and that the seal is intact. Slightly lubricate the seal with a little oil an screw on filter. Should not need to be too tight - you should not have to use tools to fasten it.